# Find a Mobius map sending the intersection of two discs to a wedge with a specific constraint on a third point

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

> Find a Mobius transformation sending the region $D$ between $|z-1|=1$ and $|z|=1$ to ${0<Arg(z)<\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ such that 1 is mapped to $i$.

My idea:
The two circles intersect at $x+iy= \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, while the two rays of the wedge intersect at $0$ and $\infty$.
I therefore thought that a reasonable way to approach this is to find a Mobius map with the following properties:
$\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i \to 0$ , $1\to i$, $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\to \infty$ and then find the map using the cross-ratio preservation:
$$
\frac{z-1}{\left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i \right)-1} \frac{\left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i \right)-\left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i \right)}{z-\left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i \right)-\left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i \right)} = \frac{M(z)-i}{0-i},
$$
where $M$ is the Mobius transformation I am looking for.

My question is:

> What is the image of the unit disc $|z|=1$ under this transformation? From a known theorem, and from $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\to\infty$ the image should be a straight line, which seems to be the imaginary axis $Re(z)=0$. But, shouldn't the image of the unit circle be one of the two rays that form the boundary of ${0<Arg(z)<\frac{2\pi}{3}}$? I am specifically confused about the image of each part of the boundary of the domain $D$.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is stated correctly? $1$ is on the boundary of the domain $D$, but $i$ is in the interior of the sector $0 < \arg z < 2 \pi/3$, which means that there is no such Möbius transformation.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, and that's exactly what I am asking. How is it possible that part of the boundary is being sent to the interior? And if such a Mobius transformation doesn't exist, what exactly does the Mobius transform I obtained does to the unit circle? and how to prove that indeed such a Mobius transformation doesn't exist?

Thank you

Comment: Möbius functions $T$ are (in particular) continuous and bijective functions from the extended complex plane (or Riemann sphere) onto itself. The interior of $D$ is mapped to the interior of $T(D)$, and the boundary of $D$ is mapped to the boundary of $T(D)$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C_1$ be the circle $|z|=1$, $C_2$ the circle $|z-1|=1$, and denote their intersections with $a = 1/2 + i \sqrt 3/2$ and $\bar a = 1/2 - i \sqrt 3/2$.

Let us ignore the condition $M(1) = i$ for a moment, and map $D$ to a sector domain. $a$ and $\bar a$ must be mappend to $0$ and $\infty$ (in some order), so a good start is
$$
 T(z) = \frac{z-a}{z-\bar a} \, .
$$
Then $C_1$ is mapped to a line $L_1$ through the origin and
$$
 T(1) = \frac{1-a}{1-\bar a} = -a = -\frac 12 - i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\, ,
$$
and $C_2$ is mapped to a line $L_2$ through the origin and
$$
 T(0) = \frac{a}{\bar a} = - \bar a = -\frac 12 + i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\, .
$$
Möbius transformations are continuous and bijective functions (aka“ homeomorphisms” aka “topological isomorphisms”) from the extended complex plane onto itself. Therefore the domain $D$ is mapped to one of the four sectors delimited by the lines $L_1$ and $L_2$.

Since $T(1/2) = -1$, $D$ is mapped to the sector
$$
 \frac{2\pi}{3} < \arg z < \frac{4\pi}{3} \, ,
$$
so that
$$
 M(z) = e^{-2\pi i/3} T(z)
$$
is a Möbius transformation which maps $D$ onto the sector $0 < \arg z < 2 \pi /3$.

Finally: $1$ is on the boundary of $D$, so that $M(1)$ is on the boundary of $M(D)$, i.e. the condition $M(1) = i$ can not be satisfied.

Comment: @Marin R: Thank you for this great answer!